# Java Date Conversion

Tags: java, date

In the following code 
input:

```
Enter Date: 3/2/2011
```

Output:

```
Entered Date is February 3, 2011
Entered Month is 02
```

Problem is , when i input this date `3/14/2012`, the date format function automatically changes month to `12+2`(*February*). If I put `13/15/2011`, it will change month to `3(12+3)`.

It should give an error on `14` that *"invalid month"*

```
package lesson4;

import java.util.*;

import java.text.*;
public class ConvertDate {
static String Month;
static String fulldate;
static int month;
static  int[] montharray={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
public static void main(String[] args){


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Enter Date: "); 
String ind = sc.nextLine(); 
//Date now = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
SimpleDateFormat m = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

Date d = null;
    Date e=null;
Date g=null;


try {
d=df.parse(ind);
e=df.parse(ind);
g=df.parse(ind);
DateFormat df3 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);


 fulldate = df3.format(d);
 Month=m.format(g);
month =Integer.parseInt(Month);

String date  =f.format(e);
 } catch (ParseException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block



e1.printStackTrace();
}





System.out.println("The entered date is: " + fulldate);
System.out.println("The entered month is: " + Month);

}
}
```

Comment: bro can you give example..i'll be greatful

Comment: @Nizil. No it won't be. DateFormat is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @RohitJain I agree, `DateFormat` is so much better than string parsing, but forgot the `setLenien(bool)` and didn't see another solution before you post your answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each of your `DateFormat` instance, you need to invoke `setLenient` with false argument:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
df.setLenient(false);
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
f.setLenient(false);
DateFormat m = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
m.setLenient(false);
```

From [`DateFormat#setLenient(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) documentation:

> With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

Comment: great Rohit..but can i want to check the month from array..i am restricted to use arrays if i enter 14 in month then it should display invalid month,....Your code is only catching exception

Comment: @JamesBlent. You can catch the exception, and display your own message. You can search for some good Exception Handling tutorial.

Comment: Yes i have cached exception that "Invalid Date"..but how can i give error using array..i have declared array in the code...please help

Comment: @JamesBlent. What do you mean by give error using array? Can you be more specific?

Comment: yes ...i want that if i enter date 14/14/2011..It should give an error that invalid month...I want that i check input value of month(14) convert it to int and compare it to my declared array..

Comment: i know how to do it..but i am actually facing problem to get 14( in input 12/14/2011)..

Comment: @JamesBlent. That will throw an exception. What do you want it to do? `14` is not a valid value for `month`.

Comment: here is a question that what i want to solve: hope you understand

Comment: Write an application in which the user can enter a date using digits and slashes  and receive output that displays the date with the month shown as a word (such as “June 24, 2012”).

Comment: Allow for the fact that the user might or
might not precede a month or day number with a zero (for example, the user might
type “06/24/2012” or “6/24/2012”). Do not allow the user to enter an invalid date,
defined as one for which the month is less than 1 or more than 12, or one for which
the day number is less than 1 or greater than the number of days in the specified
month. Also display the date’s ordinal position in the year; for example, 6/24 is the
176th day. In this application, use your knowledge of arrays

Comment: @JamesBlent. I guess, the suggestion to use arrays is for storing different `DateFormat`, rather than anything related to date, month etc. Ok, I've to go for lunch. May be I'll look into it later on.

Comment: thanks  u am waiting for you..here is my skype: usman.shafi5 ..please help

Comment: no instructions by instructor to use arrays are :  In this application, use your knowledge of arrays to store the month names,
as well as values for the number of days in each month so that you can calculate the
number of days that have passed. Figure 8-21 shows the output when the user has
entered 6/24/2012.

Comment: @JamesBlent. Well, your instructor has not given you appropriate instructions. This is not the way you convert the date to different formwat. For getting month name too, you should use DateFormat, with appropriate format. Look at the documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`, to see what all format you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Reference these formats [Java Date Format Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

[image: Formats for datetime]

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

you are expecting Month at second place while input is placing it on first.

try:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "setLenient(false)" on your DateFormat to force the DateFormat to be strict about the parsed input?
I haven't tried it yet, but stumbled across this feature recently.